# Monitoring spring web mvc application with Opentelemetry-javaagent and opentelemetry collector

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am trying to monitor an application made with spring web mvc using open telemetry. When monitoring spring boot, internal metric data such as jvm_memory_used_bytes are well received, but when observing spring web mvc, I could only receive information on run time like process_cpu_usage. The purpose is to monitor existing java applications without touching the code as much as possible (without modifying the dependency).

The current project is

```
Client
|_ opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
|_ springapplication
```

consisting of

VM options are as follows.

```
-javaagent:"path\to\opentelemetry-javaagent.jar"
-Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file="path\to\otel.properties"
```

otel.properties is a property file containing options for otel agent. The contents of the file are as follows.

```
otel.logs.exporter=otlp
otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://host:port
otel.traces.exporter=otlp
otel.resource.attributes=service.name=myserice
otel.javaagent.debug=false
otel.metrics.exporter=otlp
```

On this setting, the following metric data comes in well.

```
process_cpu_usage
process_runtime_jvm_buffer_count
process_runtime_jvm_buffer_limit_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_buffer_usage_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_classes_current_loaded
process_runtime_jvm_classes_loaded_total
process_runtime_jvm_classes_unloaded_total
process_runtime_jvm_cpu_utilization_ratio
process_runtime_jvm_gc_duration_seconds
process_runtime_jvm_memory_committed_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_memory_init_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_memory_limit_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage_after_last_gc_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage_bytes
process_runtime_jvm_system_cpu_utilization_ratio
process_runtime_jvm_threads_count
```

However, the following matrix data is observed in spring boot, but not in spring web mvc.

```
jvm_buffer_count_buffers
jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes
jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes
jvm_classes_loaded
jvm_classes_unloaded_total
jvm_gc_live_data_size_bytes
jvm_gc_max_data_size_bytes
jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total
jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total
jvm_gc_overhead_percent
jvm_gc_pause_max_seconds
jvm_gc_pause_seconds
jvm_memory_committed_bytes
jvm_memory_max_bytes
jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent
jvm_memory_used_bytes
jvm_threads_daemon
jvm_threads_live
jvm_threads_peak
jvm_threads_states
```

I want you to let me know if spring web mvc has anything to do with **not having a built-in tomcat**, should I **use jmx** to check the driving information of jvm, or if there is a **problem with my access itself**.

I've tried to use JMX, installing opentelemetry-spring-webmvc.

Comment: refer the [opentelemetry-java-instrumentation supported-libraries](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md#libraries--frameworks). we need to add opentelemetry-spring-webmvc-5.3 for all mvc feature instrumentation

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean I have to add dependency(install library) on my spring web mvc service a opentelemetry-spring-webmvc-5.3?

Comment: Yes @PurpleCoder try it.

Comment: No, you don't need to add a dependency when you use the javaagent.
You also don't need JMX.

However, I still understand the question.